# Create checked list dropdown with groups - knockoutjs

Tags: drop-down-menu, knockout.js

please look at this example of drop down checkbox list im working on..

http://jsfiddle.net/Yojik/VJHVK/143/

the problem is that im loosing the observable power by unmapping the object

what is the "knockout way" to solve this issue ?

Comment: Looking at the code you have gone down the path of concentrating on the display of the items without considering how you want to bind the data. When a child checkbox is selected what property of your model do you want this to bind to?

Comment: What behavior are you hoping for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is definitely not the knockout way of doing things - you're fighting with knockout the whole way, which is only going to cause pain.

Here's a simple example showing how to use the mapping plugin with the click event being handled by jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/VJHVK/173/

And here is a more complex example with the click event handled by knockout bindings:

http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/VJHVK/172/

Comment: so how i can expose this code as a reuseable behavior or extender?